# On click show div, image

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide, getelementbyid

I've made this code to show me a div when I click on a box:

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var bool = 0;
function showDiv() {
    if (bool == 1) {
        bool = 0;
        document.getElementById('show').style.visibility = "hidden";
    } else if (bool == 0) {
        bool = 1;
        document.getElementById('show').style.visibility = "visible";
    }
}​
</script>
```

HTML

```
<input type="button" value="click" onclick="showDiv();" />

<div id="show" style=" visibility:hidden;">
  <p>it is okay it is okay it is okay it is okay it is okay</p>
</div>
```

But, how do I do this when it's an image I want to click on to show the div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you tag your question jquery, then I recommend using `.toggle` method instead..

```
$('#yourimageid').click(function() {
   $('#targetelementid').toggle();
});
```

Comment: `.toggle()` toggles the display property, not the visibility property.

Comment: That is a good point (even if I doubt it matters for OP).. +1 for your answer

Comment: I'm sorry guys, but I still don't get it.
What I want to happen, is that when I click, on an image. A text will appear. Now, this text is in another div. It's hidden when you enter the site, and only shown when you click the Image.

Comment: And how is it different from @j08691's [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/tNEXr/1/)?

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you can reduce your code to just this:

```
$('input,img').click(function() {
    $('#show').css('visibility', ($('#show').css('visibility') == 'visible') ? 'hidden' : 'visible');
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/tNEXr/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
$('#imageId').click(showDiv);
```

To bind the `showDiv` function to the `click` event on the element whose id is imageId.

Reference : http://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way (given what you already have):

```
<img src="myimage.jpg" onclick="showDiv();"/>
```

But if you are actually using jQuery, then you could use the .toggle method which means you don't have to bother with maintaining your `bool` variable (which really ought to actually be a bool!).

With jQuery, you could do something like this:

```
$('#imageId').click(function() {
    $('show').toggle();
});
```

Comment: .toggle() toggles the display property, not the visibility property.

Comment: @j08691: So? The effect is to hide the element, which is what was wanted. If you *really* need to toggle the visibility rather than display, you can use toggleClass for example.